# How to test if a row of gridview is empty asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, dropdown, rowdatabound

I have a empty grid view at the page load .
In the RowDataBound event I add a dropdownlist to the last cell
The problem is that the ddl is shown at the page load.
I want to hide it if the cells of row are empty

```
protected void grw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlAccepted") as DropDownList;
            if (null != ddl)
            {
                string acceptedKey = (e.Row.FindControl("lblAccepted") as Label).Text;
                string acceptedValue = "";
                if (acceptedKey == "True")
                {
                    acceptedValue = "Oui";
                }
                else if (acceptedKey == "False")
                {
                    acceptedValue = "Non";
                }

                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Non", "False"));
                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Oui", "True"));

                ddl.SelectedValue = acceptedValue;
            }


        }

    }
```

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: How are you populating the gridview?

Comment: `string requete = "select '' as id,'' as caseNumber,  "'' as intervener,'' as requester,'' as SendDate, '' as recipient, "'' as ReceptionDate,'' as StateCode,'' as IsAccepted";

            grw.DataSource = GetEmptyDataSet(requete);
            grw.DataBind();`

Comment: GetEmptyDataSet returns a DataSet with no rows or with an empty row?

Comment: `public static DataTable GetEmptyDataSet(string query)
       {
           DataTable dataTable = null;
           SqlConnection connection = null;
           try
           {
               connection = Open();
               SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
               SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
               dataTable = new DataTable();
               adapter.Fill(dataTable);
           }
           finally
           {
               Close(connection);
           }
           return dataTable;
       }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution 
The empty cells have the Text equals to `&nbsp;`
So I add this line and it works

```
if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "&nbsp;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // Check if the first two cells of row are not empty
    if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "" || e.Row.Cells[1].Text != "")
    {
        DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlAccepted") as DropDownList;
        if (null != ddl)
        {
            string acceptedKey = (e.Row.FindControl("lblAccepted") as Label).Text;
            string acceptedValue = "";
            if (acceptedKey == "True")
            {
                acceptedValue = "Oui";
            }
            else if (acceptedKey == "False")
            {
                acceptedValue = "Non";
            }

            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Non", "False"));
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Oui", "True"));

            ddl.SelectedValue = acceptedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply add this `if` check to the code:

```
// Check if the first two cells of row are not empty
if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "" || e.Row.Cells[1].Text != "")
{
    //... do some other code here
}
```